# WD "My Passport" unable to be detected on Lenovo T450

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, thinkpad

I have a WD "my passport" external hard drive.  I got a new ThinkPad (Lenovo T450), and when I plug in the hard drive, the light comes on and the drive makes a "whirring" sound.  But the drive is not showing in My Computer.

I looked in Device manager - there is a yellow triangle showing up beside "unknown device" under "other devices".  I'm guessing that might be my hard drive?

It is not showing up in Disk Management either.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: try all the usb ports.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install the driver: http://support.wdc.com/KnowledgeBase/answer.aspx?ID=5419

Install the right driver, ×32 or ×64 can be checked by searching for my computer --> properties --> search for system type.

Then you can try two things:
1. You have to change the volume of the harddrive (guaranteed data loss):

Search for "diskmgmt.msc" then right click on your harddrive and remove the volume. Then set a new simple volume and problem solved. (This step will remove all the data on the hard drive!)

2. If you don't want to lose your data, you can try to set the partition als active in disk manager.

Let me know if this solved your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Judging by your description you might have some partition corruption, maybe you MFT, master file table is corrupted, in this cases I always recommend using testdisk, its the number one tool that always rescues me in this situations, since hard drives in general are pretty cheap and most likely its not broken the important part to worry about is your data and with this tool you can easily recover it, it is free and you can easily try it out, although I think there is no graphical interface, if testdisk fails to recover your data you might have to go a step further and pay for some data recovery software like getdataback for ntfs by runtime, but its a little expensive. I'll leave some links so that you can research the appropriate option.

[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)
[GetDataBack](https://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm)