# WD My passport ultra is not detected when USB 3.0 enabled in BIOS

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-3

I got new Thinkpad T450 which has 3x USB 3.0 ports. BIOS is having three modes for USB config namely Auto (default), USB 3.0 and USB 2.0

**Working Usecases**

- WD drive is detected in USB 2.0 BIOS mode when USB 3.0 cable is used
- WD drive is detected in Auto and USB 3.0 BIOS modes when USB 2.0 cable (android data cable) is used
- I have also tested with Dell Latitude E5550 which has 3x USB 3.0 ports. It is working in USB 2.0 speed when both USB 3.0/2.0 cable is used.

**Not Working Usecases**

- WD drive is not detected in Auto and USB 3.0 BIOS modes when USB 3.0 cable is used. But LED is ON and drive motor's normal vibration is felt
- diskmgmt.msc and devmgmt.msc doesn't show any change

---

I have updated Intel® USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller Driver to latest (1.0.10.255) but no change

In all the cases, WD drive is not working in USB 3.0 mode and speed is max 35 MBps

Comment: [Related question](http://superuser.com/questions/982079/wd-my-passport-unable-to-be-detected-on-lenovo-t450)

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the "USB 3.0 Host Controller Utility" and unchecking the "safe energy" box. If you do not have the actual utility, it can be downloaded [here](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t450?beta=false). Choose the Windows 7 option in the dropdown to get the utility to show.

[Source](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/274200-32-recognizing-device)

Comment: I couldn't find such utility from the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to hear about your performance issues with the WD My Passport drive, @sreeKang. I'd advise you to try using a different USB 3.0 cable and see if that will actually improve the connectivity & transfer rate. If it doesn't help, make sure you [check the warranty](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=BkfoiF) for the WD external. If it's still covered, I'd suggest you contact our [Customer Support](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=73dQfe) and let them know about your problems with the HDD. Here is a link to our [Warranty Policy](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=BB8U3B) as well.

Hope this helps.
Good luck!

Comment: I have changed the cable but no difference in speed. Drive is just 6 months old, it should have warranty. Just i have created support ticket in customer support.

Comment: Drive is faulty and it is replaced by WD. Now i got new one and everything works fine. Thanks @SuperSoph_WD

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of my WD passport external hard drive not being recognised on a USB3 port by putting a USB2 extension cable between the laptop and the hard drive - hope this solution helps others